# iOS: UILabel text setting issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel

[image: I want to place number & text in same line]

I have used **AutoLayout**. If the text is small in question number & question displaying in same line 
text is large , question displaying in 2 lines, at that time question number is displaying in between the question

I have Set the Autolayout Like this

[image: Question Number Autolayouts]
[image: Label]

i want 1st question number & question on same line Like Below Image

[image]

Comment: sorry your question is a little incomprehensible. Please edit the question and be more clear.

Comment: can u check my question , i have edited now

Comment: do you mean if question fits in a line, the number for the question and the question align together, but if question takes up multiple lines, the number aligns to the middle?

Comment: if the question is multiple line --> QuestionNumber  should be in first line

Comment: how are you rendering the numbers Q1 and Q2?

Answer (score 0):

UILabel is alway centered in the vertical axis.

What you have to do is calculate what would be the height of the UILabel considering the text given and the font size you are using.

Here is a bit of an example:

```
CGRect yourRect = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", yourTextHere]
                        boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(200, 40)
                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont whateverFontYouUse:21]}
                        context:nil];
    self.questionIdWidthConstraint.constant = yourRect.size.height + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok for the Q1 label add another constraint. `Top Space to Superview` to its parent view. That will make sure that it aligns with the first line of either a single or multi-line text